# What is the meaning of "boludo"?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, argentina, insultos

Whenever I hear some person from Argentina, it is quite common to hear him or her say a sentence containing **boludo**:

> - ¡Qué boludo!
>
> - Eres un boludo
>
> - No digas boludeces

So it seems that *boludo* is a way to curse and call somebody an *idiot*. However, what would be the complete meaning of it? Is it a word to use just among friends? Is it used in other countries throughout South America?

Also, what is its origin? There seem to be a wide range of explanations for its usage (source: [etimologías de Chile on *boludo*](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?boludo)).

Comment: I don't think of _etimologías de Chile_ as a reliable, scholarly source (it does often just gather theories that may well be misconceptions, seldom does cite any sources, etc.). That said, the first theory cited, even if not the actual origin, may well be a reason for the persistence of the word in slang (even, at times, outside Argentina). I think there is also a likely explanation in its relation with _boleadora_ carriers.

Comment: "Sos un boludo" is more frequent than "eres un boludo". I was about to say nobody (native) uses "eres" but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "boludo" is a idiomatic phrase of Argentina. The definition is:

> person that make or say stupid things. It behaves like a stupid or
> irresponsible

It can mean several things:

> asshole
>
> stupid
>
> a friendly way to refer to someone

Be careful: Only use this with a friend because it might be offensive. In other countries use other word like:

> huevón
>
> acere
>
> pelotudo

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta y bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Comment: As of lately, i've heard it being used roughly as one would use "Dude" in english, or more closely "wey" in Mexico, A modern form of "man" for youngsters, not very polite to use in good company, yet not scathing enough to be an insult.

Comment: it's right that is a modern form of "dude" for youngsters, but when you use it in a person who you don't meet or don't have good enough relation, this person can feel insulted

Answer (score 2):

Here in Argentina we use it with two meanings, as a way to curse as you perfectly explained and as a way to call a close friend instead of by the name and this can be just to tell/talk about anything and also sometimes as a way to say that he is a idiot but in a harmful way.
Some examples:

> Boludo aprende a manejar.
>
> Boludo viste el nuevo trailer de ...
>
> Sos un boludo era mas fácil si lo hacías así...

Comment: En mi experiencia viviendo allá, "boludo aprende a manejar" es algo que nececita decirse a casi cualquier conductor Argentino.  ¡Cruzar el calle es un acto medio espantoso muchas veces!

Comment: JAJAJAJA te acostumbras ....

Answer (score 1):

> Hay varias teorías respecto de su origen y uso posterior. Una de
>   ellas, bien criolla, las sitúa naciendo en las guerras de la
>   Independencia argentina, cuando nuestros gauchos peleaban contra un
>   ejército de lo que en aquella época era el Primer Mundo: el español.
>
> Frente semejante poderío, nuestros gauchos montoneros, de calzoncillo
>   cribado y botas de potro con los dedos al aire, sólo tenían para
>   oponerles pelotas (piedras grandes con un surco por donde ataban un
>   tiento) y facones (a los que algunos amarraban una caña tacuara para
>   improvisar una lanza precaria). Pocos tenían armas de fuego: algún
>   trabuco naranjero o arma larga desactualizada.
>
> ¿Y entonces cuál era la técnica para oponerse a semejante maquinaria
>   bélica como la que traían los realistas?
>
> Nuestros gauchos formaban en tres filas. La primera era la de los
>   "Pelotudos", que portaban las pelotas de piedra grandes amarradas con
>   tientos. La segunda, era la de los "Lanceros", con facones y tacuaras.
>   Y la "Tercera" la integraban los "Boludos", con sus boleadoras y
>   bolas.
>
> Cuando los españoles cargaban con su caballería, los "Pelotudos",
>   haciendo gala de una admirable valentía, los esperaban a pie firme y
>   les pegaban a los caballos en el pecho, que de esta manera rodaban y
>   desmontaban al jinete, provocando la caída de los soldados que venían
>   atrás.
>
> Los "Lanceros" aprovechaban esta circunstancia y pinchaban a los
>   caídos.
>
> Finalmente, los "Boludos", los rematan en el piso a pura boleadora.
>
> Luego, allá por 1890, un Diputado de la Nación aludiendo a lo que hoy
>   llamaríamos “perejiles”, dijo que no había que ser "tan pelotudos" en
>   referencia a que no había que ir al frente y hacerse matar.
>
> Esta fue la doble acepción que se le dio al término: 1º, aguerrido:
>   2º, estúpido. Con el tiempo se sumó a esta última clasificación la
>   palabra boludo y el imaginario popular lo fue incorporando como al que
>   los genitales grandes le impedían moverse con facilidad

http://www.diaadia.com.ar/cordoba/sabes-de-donde-provienen-las-palabras-boludo-y-pelotudo

En su significado principal actual, significa estúpido